# I did something wrong with fetching by tag in Laravel 8, using rtconner/laravel-tagging

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, tagging

I tried to fetching posts by tags. Tags have slugs, and tag link should lead to the page with tag slug in url. But I have problem with displaying posts with relevant tag on that page.

PostController. Method 'index' works well, displaying all posts with related tags. In 'fetch' method I tried to get slug for using it in function 'withAnyTag', as written in the documentation — https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging/

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('backend.post.index', compact('posts'));
}

public function fetch(Tag $tag)
{
    $slug = $tag->slug;
    $posts = Post::withAnyTag([$slug])->get()->paginate(5);

    return view('backend.post.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

In Post model nothing specific, just trait Taggable.

Routes. I see no problem with them, bring it just in case.

```
Route::get('post', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts');
Route::get('post/tag/{tag:slug}', [PostController::class, 'fetch'])->name('posts.fetch');
```

Fragment from view 'backend.post.index', using for both methods. Links work well and lead on the right url.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!! $post->title !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $post->content !!}</td>
                        <td>

                            @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
                                <a href="{{ route('posts.fetch', $tag->slug) }}">{!! $tag->name !!}</a>
                            @endforeach

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary py-0">Read Post</a>
                            <a href="{{ route('post.edit', $post->slug) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success py-0">Edit Post</a>
                            <form action="{{route('post.destroy', $post->slug)}}" method="POST">
                                @method('DELETE')
                                @csrf
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger py-0">Delete</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
@endforeach

{!! $posts->links() !!}
```

But, when I click on tag and get to the page '.../post/tag/tag-slug', appears an error 'Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.' In method 'index' was no mistake with pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should run `paginate` directly on the `withAnyTag` method like this

```php
$posts = Post::withAnyTag([$slug])->paginate(5);
```

You don't need the separate call to `get()` as `paginate` will run the query and return a paginated result.